# Show Uploading Percentage status in loader

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery, spfx, pnpjs

I have a question about uploading file via PnP JS SPFx in SharePoint online. I had successfully uploaded files via PnP JS. After that, I need to show uploading percentage.

Same requirement, using REST API I get percentage value using this link [Show a progress on multiple file upload Jquery/Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23219033/show-a-progress-on-multiple-file-upload-jquery-ajax)

Same approach not working in SP PnP JS. If anyone has an answer then help me. Is there any way to get uploading percentage in SP PnP JS SharePoint online(spfx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the solution for my question. Instead of Using **files.add** in sp-pnp-js am used **addChunked** Method. Refer This [Link](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Working-With:-Files).

Using **addChunked** method we upload the files as number of little blocks sized 10MB. Using Total number of blocks, add some javascript code to convert percentage.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting approach is to use **UI Fabric** controls that are more consistent with the SharePoint Online design. There are different progress controls: *ProgressIndicators*, *Shimmer*, *Spinner*. Best suited to your needs is **ProgressIndicators**, but it does not allow you to display the percentage as it is implemented by default.

Control behaviour in action [here](https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true). You can read more details about ProgressIndicators control [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/progressindicator).

**UPDATE**

There is a percentage property that can be implemented as shown in the following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your approach. I tried it Before once.As you say this only show loader,shimmer not percentage.
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I updated the answer

Comment: If you find my answer useful, kindly upvote and accept it as answer, so that it will help others too.

Comment: Thanks a lot bAbdenour. I find the another solution in sp-pnp-js with some extra javascript code. another one time thanks a lot...

Comment: You're welcome. You can share it in answer to your question to help the community.

Comment: yeah ofcourse...